# "WinError 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Tags: python, networking, pickle

When a client sends data to the server using
`pickle.dumps(player)` and i try to unpickle it at the server using `pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))` it gives me the error `[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` .

This is the code for the server:

```
def threadedClient(conn, gameId, id):
    games[gameId].connections = id # storing how many connections have been made

    conn.send(pickle.dumps(games[gameId]))
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(games[gameId]))
                games[id].players[id] = pickle.loads(data)
        except:
            break

    print(f"Disconnected client: {id} from game: {gameId}")
    conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)

    start_new_thread(threadedClient, (conn, gameId, clientId))
```

The client:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        # creating the screen
        pygame.display.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RES)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # networking setup
        self.n = Network()
        self.player = Player()

        try:
            self.game = self.n.getGame()
            self.clientId = self.game.connections
            self.game.players.append(self.player)
        except AttributeError:
            print("No server found, Please start a server to connect clients")
            sys.exit()

        pygame.display.set_caption(f"Client: {self.clientId} Game: {self.game.id}")

    def main(self):
        self.run = True
        while self.run:
            self.clock.tick(60)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    self.run = False
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        self.run = False

            # drawing to the screen
            self.update()
            pygame.display.update()

        # destroying this client and player
        pygame.quit()
        self.game.players.remove(self.player)
        self.game.connections -= 1

    def update(self):
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOUR)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_a]:
            self.player.rect.x -= 3
        if keys[K_d]:
            self.player.rect.x += 3

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 200, 0), self.player.rect)

        self.game = self.n.send(self.player)
```

The network:

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = SERVER
        self.port = PORT
        self.game = self.connect()

    def getGame(self):
        return self.game

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect((self.server, self.port))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, objData):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(objData))
            recvData = self.client.recv(2048)
            #print(recvData)
            return pickle.loads(recvData)
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

The player class only contains a `pygame.Rect`

I removed the `games[gameId].players[id] = pickle.loads(data)`  from the server and the error was fixed but `games[gameId].players[id]` still needs to be the player class sent from the client.